# unmarshel from XML of hiearchy object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have follow XML structure:

```
A
  AAA
     CCC
     BBB
     CCC
     BBB
  DDD
     CCC
     BBB
     CCC
```

How to unmarshell such structure by JAXB, is it possible?

Comment: image <a><aaa><ccc> ....

I forget to say, that CCC and BBB have different names, but similar structure

Answer (score 1):

This structure works fine

```
    @XmlRootElement
    public class AAA {
       @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "BBB", type = AbstractBC.BBB.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "CCC", type = AbstractBC.CCC.class)
       })
       public List<AbstractBC> tables;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to represent that XML structure with JAXB.

When you are unsure how to map something in JAXB, the easiest way to figure out the mapping is to create an XML schema for your XML representation and then run the XML Schema to Java (XJC) utility to see what the class model looks like.